# nginx dynamic servername with regular expression doesn't work for co.uk

Tags: nginx, http, perl, regex, regular-expressions

I'm trying to setup a nginx server which dynamically loads content from a folder for a domain. To do this I'm using regular expressions in the server name like so:

`server_name ((?<subdomain>.+)\.)?(?<domain>.+)\.(?<tld>.*);`

This will create a 3 variables for nginx to use later on, for example when using the following url: `test.foo.example.com` this will evaluate to:

1. $subdomain = test.foo
2. $domain = example
3. $tld = com

The problem arises when the co.uk top-level domain is used. In this case when using the url `test.foo.example.co.uk`it will evaluate to:

1. $subdomain = test.foo.cedira
2. $domain = co
3. $tld = uk

How can I edit the regular expression so that it will also work for co.uk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is possible to define multiple server_names, so I simply made two regular expressions as the server_name if the first one fails it will automatically go for the second one.

```
server_name ~^((?<subdomain>.+)\.)?(?<domain>.+)\.(?<tld>co.uk)$ ~^((?<subdomain>.+)\.)?(?<domain>.+)\.(?<tld>.*)$;
```

I'm guessing it can also be done with one regular expression I would still like to know how but for now I will use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is able to check for the www part and also it gets just the first capture as the subdomain second capture as domain and the rest as the host-domain:

```
server_name ~^(www\.)?((?<subdomain>.+?)\.)?((?<domain>.+?)\.)?(?<host_domain>.+)\.(?<tld>co.uk)$ ~^(www\.)?((?<subdomain>.+?)\.)?((?<domain>.+?)\.)?(?<host_domain>.+)\.(?<tld>.*)$;
```

Comment: This is able to check for the www part and also it gets just the first capture as the subdomain second caputure as domain and the rest as the host-domain

Comment: You can always edit your own answers and do not need to comment on them to provide clarification